# Generating multiple rows from a single row, based on the number in the cell next to it

Tags: google-sheets, concatenation, transpose, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

[This SQL question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56455876/generating-multiple-rows-from-a-single-row-based-on-dates) explains exactly what I would like to achieve in Google Sheets.

Would it be possible to create some automation in Google sheet, that read through the sheet, and changes single rows into multiple rows, based on the number in the cell next to it?

Comment: "Would it be possible"? Yes. Go right ahead.

Comment: Alright, thanks. Any suggestions on how to go on about it?

Comment: Well, I think I'd write a script; use the monthly count to loop through the the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you want the exact example in your link, with dates?

But anyway, here is a formula version of it:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(row(C2:C)<sum(C2:C)+2,
eomonth(vlookup(row(C2:C)-2,{sumif(row(C2:C),"<="&row(C2:C),C2:C)-C2:C,B2:B},2,true)
,row(C2:C)-3-vlookup(row(C2:C)-2,sumif(row(C2:C),"<="&row(C2:C),C2:C)-C2:C,1,true))+1,""))
```

And to get the amount

```
=ArrayFormula(vlookup(row(C2:C)-2,{sumif(row(C2:C),"<="&row(C2:C),C2:C)-C2:C,E2:E},2,true))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This solution is the one I ended up using - and it did the job perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

```
=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(",", ARRAYFORMULA(REPT(SPLIT(
 INDIRECT("A1:A"&COUNTA(A1:A)), ",")&",", 
 INDIRECT("B1:B"&COUNTA(B1:B))))), ","))
```

[image: 0]